# Shell script to use my login environment

Tags: shell, cron

I have crontab running a shell script periodically. I need the script to run in the same environment that I usually log in. Can I just simply add this line in 2nd line of the script (after shebang).

```
source /home/<my username>/.cshrc
```

Or what's the proper way to set the cron shell process to use my login environment?

PS: I am quite sure which exactly setting is needed by my script, so I can only source the whole .cshrc.

Comment: can't you make a simple test script that would confirm that adding `source ...` will solve your problem? (I believe it will, but don't have access to csh). Just echo some vars that are only set in the .cshrc. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
sudo su - <user> -c <cmd>
```

Of course you have to alter the sudoers file first.
Take a look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).

*hth*